# Channel to bulk capacitance in inversion

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, capacitance, semiconductors

[This](http://www.doe.carleton.ca/~len/477W2003/LectureNotes/January_15_2003_2up.pdf) lecture (page 11) said that as Vgs increases further, the inversion layer forms and
the channel to bulk capacitance is “shielded”. So the channel to bulk capacitance is 0.

Could anyone explain why? What does "shield" actually mean here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A capacitance is the result of a field between two plates.

For the MOSCAP in depletion the first plate is the gate and the second the bulk. As soon as the transistor gets into inversion a channel forms and acts like a third plate.

Since the channel is *between* the gate and the bulk the field lines originating from the gate will terminate on the channel. The bulk is effectively shielded and instead of a gate-bulk capacitance a gate-channel capacitance is seen.

Comment: Thank you. In the depeletion region, there is no electric field so the capacitance is 0? Is this an theory?

Also from the site below (page 4) says that in strong inversion the junction capacitor and Cox are in parallel. Could you explain why?
http://www.aicdesign.org/SCNOTES/2010notes/Lect2UP060_(100324).pdf

Comment: Which capacitance should be zero? The depletion region is of no importance since the channel screens it. The junction capacitance is something completely different, it would be important for a reverse biased junction.

Comment: Hi, is the channel to bulk capacitance called junction capacitance?

Comment: Hi, is the channel to bulk capacitance called junction capacitance?
If I am not mistaken. It is from the link above (page 3).

Comment: The gate to bulk capacitance will be the total of gate to channel and channel to bulk (junction capacitor) in series. 
However, as the link below (page 3 and 4) the gate to channel and channel to bulk capacitors are in parallel in strong inversion. 
I dont see how they can be parallel here. Could you explain that?
http://www.aicdesign.org/SCNOTES/2010notes/Lect2UP060_(100324).pdf

Comment: The channel is at fixed potential. A capacitance in series would not change anything.

Comment: So, could you explain why the lecture in the given link above said that junction capacitor and Cox are in parallel in strong inversion?

Comment: @anhnha  Consider it 3 capacitors in subvt: \$C_g, C_s, C_d\$; however, in strong inversion, none of those really matter because \$C_d\$ is at "pinchoff" on the drain side.  The source capacitor is unchanged

Comment: Thank you. I think it is better to end this and I will open another thread for the question above.